# What is the easiest way to install ImageMagick for Spree on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, imagemagick, spree

I want to try Spree on windows and am following the Getting Started guide, but I failed to install ImageMagick.

Is there a convenient way to install ImageMagick for spree?

Comment: adding a link to official docs : https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've been on Windows, but I know that ImageMagick offers a binary distribution for Windows. This may get you started.

[http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Spree throuh XAMPP or similar?

I use Imagemagick with XAMPP and just installed it from the binary as suggested by Chris; it worked without any other setting up.